# How to move this function call out of my HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms

I am trying to change a javascript function that uses a inline event handler to one that of one with a more modern approach. I would like to remove the ugly event handler from the actual  HTML markup and put it in a modular external javascript file. Here is the test case:

Here is the current code (working fine as far as functionality is concerned

```
function formatPhone(obj) {
   var numbers = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
       char = {0:'(',3:') ',6:' - '};
   obj.value = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       obj.value += (char[i]||'') + numbers[i];
   }
}
```

---

What I would like to accomplish is something like this:

```
var TargetEl = $('[name="pnumb"]');
TargetEl.on('blur', function() {
var UserInput = $('[name="pnumb"]').value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
char = {0:'(',3:') ',6:' - '};
TargetEl.value = '';

for (var i = 0; i < UserInput.length; i++) {
    TargetEl.value += (char[i]||'') + numbers[i];
}
```

My main focus is to remove the inline js and onblur="" event handler.I also want have the phone number formatted after the targeted El is blurred. Lastly I want this to be called by simply assigning a class of say .pnumbFormat...  (Thanks in advance for your help SO!)

Here is the fiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/UberNerd/ae4fk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function to accept string and return string.

```
function formatPhone(value) {
    var numbers = value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        char = {
            0: '(',
            3: ') ',
            6: ' - '
        };
    value = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        value += (char[i] || '') + numbers[i];
    }
    return value;
}

var TargetEl = $('[name="pnumb"]');
TargetEl.on('blur', function () {
    $(this).val(formatPhone($(this).val()))
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ae4fk/1/)

---

**Even better**

Thanks @KevinB for Great improvisation.

```
function formatPhone(_,value) {
    var numbers = value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        char = {
            0: '(',
            3: ') ',
            6: ' - '
        };
    value = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        value += (char[i] || '') + numbers[i];
    }
    return value;
}

var TargetEl = $('[name="pnumb"]');
TargetEl.on('blur', function () {
    $(this).val(formatPhone)
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ae4fk/4/)

Comment: and you can simplify it by turning `formatPhone` into something that could be passed directly to .val by reference. http://pastebin.com/DayRNzGv and `$(this).val(formatPhone)`

Comment: Your edit, if you add another parameter to `formatPhone` before `value`, you can pass it directly to `.val`. http://jsfiddle.net/ae4fk/4/

Comment: @KevinB, Great improvisation. Its tempting to add it to answer

Comment: Add it if you wish. just wanted to point out a commonly missed way of using .val. As a separate answer it wouldn't have provided anything new.

Comment: THANKS! You guys rock, where would I be without the kindness of strangers?

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, consider adding an attribute so you know which fields to format.

```
<input value="22" type="text" name="pnumb" data-formatter="phone" />
```

Then in your JavaScript, you can select those elements and set up the handlers:

```
$('input[data-formatter="phone"]').each(function (index, element) {
  // Add blur handlers or whatever here.
});
```

This way, you only need to add that attribute to your markup, and your global JS takes care of it.  Much less to hook up on a per-page basis.